# CSS - Nested rows in table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to create a table exactly like this:

[image: The table I'm modeling]

I don't have access to the website so I can't quite inspect the table.

Initially I tried with **tables**, it works with margin-left to move a little bit the sub-item, but a div inside a row does not take full height and I want to have a **border-bottom exactly like in the image** (which starts after the left margin) and could not manage to make it work

I also tried using div as **trees**, like so:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="parent">
    </div>
</div>
```

with style

```
.parent > .parent { margin-left: 25px; }
```

but I can't figure out how to create the **right side of the table**, because the next items after Name have to respect the table grid, which I do not know how to do it

There's also a hack to use classes like **sub-item** (margin: 20px), **sub-item-2** (margin: 40px) but I consider it a hack so I would like not to use them, unless I have no choice

Do you have a ***snippet*** or any ***idea*** how to do this?
I'm not asking for the whole code, I only need to know the idea behind this

Comment: Your link doesn't work.

Comment: It works for me. I changed the link, try now please

Comment: I would consider this question as too broad... But to be as general as you are ;) your tree-approach is most likely to be succesful. Just read a [tree structure css tutorial](http://www.thecssninja.com/css/css-tree-menu), or [google some more](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+tree+structure) for inspiration. That should point you to the right direction.

Comment: I don't think you understood me. I do know how to create a tree, it's easy nesting divs, I need a table tree, which is different. You don't nest rows in rows

Comment: Why wouldn't you nest rows in rows? or nest a row-container in a row?

Answer (score 0):

Keeping everything in a table and using `ul` instead of `div`should work I think. With a bit of JavaScript simply `insertRow()` and `deleteRow()` when the list is shown/hidden.